# htacess redirect - changing the query part of a URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

Google picked up the following URL and ranked it:

*http://www.example.com/yyy/zzz-99.php?item_id=99&sort=1* (the *item_id=99* part should not be there).

Since I picked up the error and fixed it, I have added the following line to my htaccess:

```
RedirectPermanent /yyy/zzz-99.php?item_id=99&sort=1 http://www.example.com/yyy/zzz-99.php?&sort=1
```

However that redirect does not work. Any clue on what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, from the manual page: _"mod_alias is designed to handle simple URL manipulation tasks. For more complicated tasks such as **manipulating the query string**, use the tools provided by mod_rewrite."_

Comment: Thanks! The -1 is harsh but I'll take it. Of course I did as much research as I could given my knowledge.

Comment: The `-1` is undeserved IMHO. It _is_ in the docs, but so easily overlooked that most people only know about it because they've been burned before ;) (easily shown by the veritable swaths of wrong, and only 1 right answer here below at the moment).

Comment: +1 The question is useful because the answer is so messed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need mod_rewrite to achieve even that single replacement, because includes a query string.

You may try this in the .htaccess file in root directory, provided mod_rewrite is enabled:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/yyy/zzz-99\.php  [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  item_id=99&sort=1  [NC]
RewriteRule .*        /yyy/zzz-99.php?&sort=1?  [NC,L,R=301]
```

Redirects

`http://www.example.com/yyy/zzz-99.php?item_id=99&sort=1` to

`http://www.example.com/yyy/zzz-99.php?&sort=1`

For silent mapping, remove R=301 from [NC,L,R=301].

Comment: Thanks faa. Looks good to me but it doesn't work. I do have mod_rewrite enabled, so that's not the issue.

Comment: I've edited my question with your code. I'm sure it must be pretty close... that's driving me crazy!

Comment: Did you mean to put a `?` on the *end* of the RewriteRule?  @Tioneb: try without that second `?`.  Maybe backslash-escape the other punctuation in the RewriteCond directives?

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone Thanks. I tried that, it didn't change anything.

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone The trailing `?` is there to stop the query from being appended again, as normally it is added automatically.

Comment: Please copy-paste in a comment the complete testing URL. Looks like there isn't any redirection and that happens when one of the conditions is not met. Are you making sure the browser's cache is cleared before any test?

Comment: @faa I'm coming around to believing [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) on this byzantine  mod_rewrite do in fact say that you want a terminating `?` even when you already have a `?` inside the substitution string:  "use a question mark inside the substitution string to indicate that the following text should be re-injected into the query string. When you want to erase an existing query string, end the substitution string with just a question mark."

Comment: Thanks Faa. I've learnt a lot here :) Got it to work using your solution.

Answer (score -1):

Check the name of your .htaccess file. Make sure it starts with a period.

```
redirect 301 /index.html http://www.domain.com/index.html 
redirect permanent /index.html http://www.domain.com/index.html 
redirectpermanent /index.html http://www.domain.com/index.html
```

Answer (score -1):

use 301 redirect in .htaccess:

Redirect 301 http://www.example.com/yyy/zzz-99.php?item_id=99&sort=1 http://www.example.com/yyy/zzz-99.php?sort=1

Redirect 301 (from) (to)